# How to check if Vuex state object is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an initial empty object in Vuex state that gets updated from an API.

```
const state = {
  someObject: {}
}
```

How do I check if the object is empty in my template?

```
<template>
  <div v-if="someObject">
    This should not display when someObject is empty.
  </div>
</template>
```

What is best practice for checking if a state object is set/empty or not?

Should i set `someObject: null/undefined/false` initially, even if it expects to be updated with a new object?

Does it make sense to do a check in getters?

```
export const someObject = state => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(state.someObject).length == 0 ? state.someObject : false
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use the lodash method: `_.isEmpty({someObject});`

Or if you wanted to do a getter:

```
computed:{
  objectLength(state){
    return Object.keys(state.someObject).length
  }
```

Comment: That works for an object but if your state has a lot of different types it becomes tedious to write all kinds of different checks.

Answer (score 7):

Depending  on particular use case I would ether set it to null/undefined or make if check by some required object property like v-if='someObject.id'

Anything else seams as unnecessary complication.

Comment: So it's ok to use this as a default state? `const state = {
  someObject: undefined
}`

Comment: Yes perfectly fine. FYI based on ecmascript specification on null/undefined in this case it would be more appropriate to use null instead of undefined.  "The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value."

Comment: I've run into some buggy stuff initializing store objects to null.  Empty objects are the way to go.